# What is the meaning of the "Removed" section in Conda repositories

Tags: json, anaconda, conda

When downloading the `repodata.json` file from Conda main repository as follows:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/numpy-devel-1.14.3-py36ha22f7c6_2.tar.bz2
```

At the end of the `repodata.json` file, we can see a `Removed` section:

```
"removed": [
    "libtiff-4.0.10-h2733197_1001.conda",
    "libtiff-4.0.10-h2733197_1001.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py27h28100ab_6.conda",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py27h28100ab_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py27hcd700cb_6.conda",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py27hcd700cb_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py36h28100ab_6.conda",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py36h28100ab_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py36hcd700cb_6.conda",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py36hcd700cb_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py37h28100ab_6.conda",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py37h28100ab_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py37hcd700cb_6.conda",
    "numpy-1.11.3-py37hcd700cb_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py27h28100ab_2.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py27h28100ab_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py27hcd700cb_2.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py27hcd700cb_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py35h28100ab_2.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py35h28100ab_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py35hcd700cb_2.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py35hcd700cb_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py36h28100ab_2.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py36h28100ab_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py36hcd700cb_2.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.3-py36hcd700cb_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-1.14.5-py35h28100ab_0.conda",
    "numpy-1.14.5-py35h28100ab_0.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py27h2b20989_6.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py27h2b20989_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py27hdbf6ddf_6.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py27hdbf6ddf_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py36h2b20989_6.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py36h2b20989_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py36hdbf6ddf_6.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py36hdbf6ddf_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py37h2b20989_6.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py37h2b20989_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py37hdbf6ddf_6.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.11.3-py37hdbf6ddf_6.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py27h2b20989_2.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py27h2b20989_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py27hdbf6ddf_2.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py27hdbf6ddf_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py35h2b20989_2.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py35h2b20989_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py35hdbf6ddf_2.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py35hdbf6ddf_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py36h2b20989_2.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py36h2b20989_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py36hdbf6ddf_2.conda",
    "numpy-base-1.14.3-py36hdbf6ddf_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py27h025eb46_2.conda",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py27h025eb46_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py27ha22f7c6_2.conda",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py27ha22f7c6_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py35h025eb46_2.conda",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py35h025eb46_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py35ha22f7c6_2.conda",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py35ha22f7c6_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py36h025eb46_2.conda",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py36h025eb46_2.tar.bz2",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py36ha22f7c6_2.conda",
    "numpy-devel-1.14.3-py36ha22f7c6_2.tar.bz2"
  ],
```

I want to know what is the official meaning of this section? Why do these packages located under the `Removed` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all revoked packages. While I can't know without insider knowledge (perhaps ask Kale Franz, since he's the uploader on the NumPy ones), presumably there was a bug of some sort discovered *in the build* (as distinct from the package) which was corrected and a new build was released (though still the same package version).  I'd guess all the packages listed here were revoked simultaneously, which is why they are listed together.  Looking through the files that are still on Anaconda Cloud (e.g, [**numpy-devel**](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy-devel/files?version=1.14.3)), the upload date to include the `package_has_been_revoked` dependency is from about one year ago.